# Python Library Can Detect Graphic Card

Tags: python, graphic

I am trying finding a library of Python that could detect the model of a graphics card. For a better graphics card, there is a higher score associated with it, because I need to configure a game's display based on the performance of graphic card.

Answer (score 0):

If you take this approach, you will have to maintain an ever changing database of graphics cards and the performance capabilities of each. Typically, options are available to the user for changing texture quality, terrain/water detail, shadows, lighting, anti-aliasing, etc. There is also usually a test where the game renders a scene, and based on the frame rate the game can set ideal presets for most of the graphics options.